# Python csv seek() not working

Tags: python, csv, io

Hi I am trying to read a csv file using the following code. I want to read from `n` th line to `m` th line of the csv file provided. As a example I want to start reading from 10th line to 100 line and after that start from 500th line to 1000th line. I give those parameters using `start` and `end` variables.

The problem that **it always start from the beginning regardless the start and end variables.** i tried and tried for a solution but failed.Can anyone help me to figure out the issue here.? Thanks a lot! (there are some duplicate questions but no one seems to have given a solution)

```
    import csv
    import os

    with open('file.csv','r') as csvfile:
        start=10
        end=100
        csvfile.seek(start)
        r= csv.reader(csvfile)
        r.next()
        for i in range(start,end):
            try:
                url=r.next()[2]
                print url
            except IndexError,e:
                print str(e),
            except ValueError,b:
                print b
        csvfile.close()
```

Comment: The parameter to `seek` is in bytes, not lines.

Comment: :( isnt there any way to seek to lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv

n = 3
m = 5

read = 0
with open("so.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for record in reader:
        read += 1
        if read >= n and read <= m:
            print(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through csv file lines and get lines you want like this:

```
import csv

def read_lines(file_name, start, end):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in csvreader:
            if csvreader.line_num >= start and csvreader.line_num <= end:
                print ', '.join(row)
            else:
                continue

read_lines('test.csv', 10,12)
```

**Update:**

From documentation: `csvreader.line_num: The number of lines read from the source iterator. This is not the same as the number of records returned, as records can span multiple lines.`

Comment: Note that [`line_num`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.csvreader.line_num) is *not the number of records* because records can span multiple lines!

Comment: I tried this but it seems the reader is missing some records. The csv file contains precisely one record per line. Anyway thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You should check what's the delimiter and quotechar in your csv file and change the code accordingly

Comment: I used `delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC ` for writing this csv file but after putting same in to the csv reader, it gives following error. **could not convert string to float: Page Number 
**